# RadGrid row disable issue?

Tags: wpf, silverlight-4.0, telerik, radgrid

Can anyone help me to see why this code disables all the rows even when the condition is only met once?

```
    private void RollListGrid_RowLoaded(object sender, RowLoadedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (masterList[0].Rolls[0].IsActive = false)
            e.Row.IsEnabled = false;

        foreach (var roll in masterList.Where(s => s.StudentId == StudentID))
        {
            foreach (var v in roll.MasterEnrolmentStatusList.Values)
            {
                if (v != null)
                    EnrolmentStatus.Add(v.Value.ToString());
            }
        }


        foreach (var status in EnrolmentStatus)
        {
            if (status == "Confirmed")
                e.Row.IsEnabled = false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to achieve what I needed to with the below code.

```
    foreach (var x in e.Row.Cells)
        {

            if (((GridViewCell)x).Value != null && ((GridViewCell)x).Value.ToString() == "Confirmed" && x.Column.UniqueName.IndexOf("5") != -1)
            {
                e.Row.IsEnabled = false;
                break;
            }
        }
```